# SendWakeFull Work is not called

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have implemented the Commonsware WakefulIntentService jar file in my project.

I have setup new alarms as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Get the AlarmManager service
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// CONSTANT.ALARM_TIME is set to 300000
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,   SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+CONSTANT.ALARM_TIME, CONSTANT.ALARM_TIME, pi);
```

I setup the Broadcast Receiver as follows:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, AlarmService.class);
  }
}
```

I have debugged this setup and when I set a breakpoint in the AlarmReceiver class, it fires.

However, a breakpoint in the doWakeFulWork, and it never gets there.

```
import com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService;

public class AlarmService extends WakefulIntentService implements OFDelegate {
private MMApp myApp;
private Account _currentAccount;
private ArrayList<Thread> _threads;

private static final String SHOW_TIME_FORMAT = "h:mma";

private final static String CLASS_NAME = AlarmService.class.getName();

public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
}

@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You perhaps have not listed your service in the manifest. Also, an `IntentService` -- let alone a `WakefulIntentService` -- should not be forking its own threads, so I suspect that you will need to look elsewhere for a solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare, that was it.  I had a typo in my Manifest.  Arg.  Sorry to bother.  Regarding the Threads comment, I want to get the notification out and then do some work that isn't critical for the notification.  However, in the OnDestroy, I will do a thread.join() to make sure all threads are completed before exiting.  Is this a problem?

Comment: I ended up taking the threading as I was getting a DB lock doing it that way.  I just adjusted the work to after the notification was sent.  Thanks again @CommonsWare.  It's a great library and after spending much time trying to get this to work on my own..worked first time with your library.  My users will be really happy now!  I would like to accept your answer...but there doesn't appear to be a way to do that.

Comment: Mine was a comment, not an answer, in large part because I was just guessing as to what your problem is. Glad to hear things are working for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Commonsware was correct.  I had the entries in the manifest, but there was a typo.  Once I corrected that typo, doWakefulWork was called correctly.  Thanks to @Commonsware for his help and a great library.  Highly recommended!